# texdoc fail on mac osx: texlua requires unavailable version of libpng?

Tags: texdoc

I have recently installed TeXLive on Mac OSX Yosemite from this link

```
https://tug.org/mactex/
```

I then find texdoc as follows

```
$ which texdoc
/opt/local/bin/texdoc
```

When I run it, I get an error

```
$ texdoc pgf
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libpng15.15.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/texlua
  Reason: Incompatible library version: texlua requires version 
33.0.0 or later, but libpng15.15.dylib provides version 31.0.0
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I then try a fix

```
$ brew upgrade
$ brew update
$ brew doctor
$ brew uninstall libpng
$ brew install libpng
... outputs don't show any obvious problems ...
```

but that did not work.  I'd be grateful for any advice how to uncapsize and salvage my installation.  The only thing I can think of to do is wipe the machine and start over completely from scratch :(

Comment: I'm under the impression that your `texdoc` is provided by some old installation with MacPorts, because if the MacTeX provided `texdoc` is used, the answer from `which texdoc` should be `/usr/texbin/texdoc`. Note that the `libpng` currently installed by Homebrew is version 16.16

Comment: It's possible that some old MacPorts stuff needs to be cleaned out!  That's a good tip for me to try, and I can try it later today.

Answer (score 1):

> Incompatible library version: `texlua` requires version 
>   `33.0.0` or later, but `libpng15.15.dylib` provides version 31.0.0

It sounds like `libpng` was outdated on your system, so if Homebrew doesn't provide the newest version, formula can be edited manually by `brew edit libpng` and `url` changed to the one which is supported.

At the time of writing, `libpng` has relevant version available with Homebrew:

```
$ brew update
$ brew reinstall libpng
$ otool -L $(brew list libpng | grep dylib$)
/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.32/lib/libpng.dylib:
    /usr/local/opt/libpng/lib/libpng16.16.dylib (compatibility version 49.0.0, current version 49.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.8)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1238.50.2)
```